# Is "I see my freedom restricted" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Could you please tell me whether the following sentence is really grammatical and why?

> I see my freedom restricted.

Comment: It's grammatical, but you need to tell us what makes you think it might not be, so we can answer your specific concern.

Comment: What are you trying to mean? There are loads of cases where something is grammatically correct, but carry a different meaning than what you wanted. (e.g. I go to camp vs. I go camping).

Comment: @StoneyB I can't say things like "I see this tree tall." Is that correct?

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost I imagine being in a situation where I don't have some kind of freedom and where I wan't to complain to somebody about it.

Comment: @fill - Yes, you're correct that you can't say "I see this tree tall".  But *restricted* is a participle, whereas *tall* is an adjective.  That's where the difference lies.

Comment: @stangdon So the following sentences are correct, as well?

"I see him beaten up.", "I see the place devastated.", "I see the moon destroyed.", "I see the wall painted."

Comment: Yes, those are all correct. This is more of a stylistic problem. While those sentences don't sound very natural to *say*, as @Nihilist_Frost said it just depends what the author or speaker is trying to emphasize. You should provide more context to where you heard or saw this sentence.

Comment: Yes, they're all grammatically correct.  They're not necessarily natural, as others have pointed out, or very clear without more context, but they are correct.  A good example of this kind of construction is in Allen Ginsburg's *Howl*: "I saw the best minds of my generation destroyed by madness..." (although *Howl* is so strange you shouldn't generally use it as an example of good grammar and usage)

Comment: Yes, sentences phrased that way seem a little strange at first, but they have a nice effect when used in poetry or a speech.  You probably would not use them for something as mundane as a wall being painted, but a place being devastated, freedom being restricted, or the moon being destroyed would definitely important enough that it might be used.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. Should I delete the question?